# Android notification Big View - Intent on button not fired

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I'm following the [Android Dev](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded.html#big-view) tutorial to use `Big View` for notifications. I want an `on going` notification with some functionality when clicking on the body of the notification and other functionality when clicking the Button.
This is my code:

```
Intent bodyIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
innerIntent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_BODY, "Click on notification body");  
PendingIntent bodyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, bodyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Intent buttonIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
buttonIntent.setAction(NOTIFICATION_BUTTON);
PendingIntent buttonPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, buttonIntent, 0);

android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("My notification")
                .setContentText("Hello World!")
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE)
                .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setLights(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary), 50, 10000)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setVibrate(new long[] {0, 50})
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Hello World BIG!"))
                .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_image, "Button", buttonPendingIntent);
int mNotificationId = 001;
NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
```

Then in `onResume`:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Log.e("m", String.valueOf(intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_RESULT, 0)));
    Log.e("m", String.valueOf(intent.getAction()));
```

**Result:**

When clicking on the body of the notification the `bodyIntent` fires and I get the correct `log` printing.

When clicking on the button: Nothing happens and `MainActivity` not even starting.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `PendingIntent.getActivity()` method if you want to start an activity, but you are creating `buttonPendingIntent` by calling `PendingIntent.getService()`.